# Conditioning on Random Variables and equivalence in Expectation

Tags: probability-theory

I'm looking over an article, and there's a statement that I want to fully understand.  I know the following $Y(x)$ is a random (real valued) variable parameterized by $x$, such that $\mathbb{E}[Y(x)]=M(x)$ is some known function.  Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{Z_n\}_{n=}^\infty$ be sequences of real valued random variables.  Suppose that we know that 
\begin{equation*}
Z_n|_{Z_1,Z_2,\ldots, Z_{n-1}}\sim Y(X_n),
\end{equation*}
with the $\sim$ denoting equivalence in distribution.  Now, consider the $\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal{G}_n$ generated as
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{G}_n =\sigma(X_1, Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_{n-1}),
\end{equation*}
What I want to convince myself of is that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[Z_n\mid\mathcal{G}_n] = M(X_n)
\end{equation*}

Comment: Missing independence hypotheses.

Comment: What do you think needs to be assumed to be independent?  My reading of the article is that $Y(X_n)$ is independent of $Z_n$ with the conditioning.  Is that sufficient?